# method to dealt with database connection in PHP's function

Tags: php, database, function

I prepared mySQL connection like this

```
$connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'quiz')  ;

// sprawdz polaczenie
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
echo "error is here". mysqli_connect_error();
}
else
echo "connected";

echo "<br>";

$query=('SELECT * from question') ;
$result=$connection->query($query);
mysqli->close($connection);
```

Now if i will want to use `$connection` in PHP function i will not have an access to `$connection`

What is the best practice to dealt with that ? i cant prepare next connection over and over in functions

Comment: donot `close()` your `$connection`.

Comment: you can pass `$connection` as a parameter to your functions, like this `function myFunction($conn){ ... }` and call it like this `myFunction($connection)`

Comment: If you plan to have just one connection, why not make it a global. Then, it will be available in all functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Dont close your connection**

remove this line: `$mysqli->close($connection);`

**2. You can use "global"**

```
$connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'quiz')  ;

// sprawdz polaczenie
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
echo "error is here". mysqli_connect_error();
}
else
echo "connected";

do_something();

function do_something(){
    global $connection; //Function now knows to use $connection from global scope
    $connection->query("yourqueryhere");

    //or
    $_GLOBALS['connection']->query("yourqueryhere");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you made $connection in the global scope (outside of any classes or functions), you can use it in a function with the $GLOBALS superglobal.

```
function foo() {
    ... some code ...
    $result = $GLOBALS['connection']->query('some query');
    ... some code ...
}
```

See Example 2 here: http://php.net/language.variables.scope